# Need some help creating a JQuery Calculator

Tags: javascript, jquery, calculator

I volunteered to create an impact calculator for a small non-profit organization and I'm needing some guidance on how to code it. The calculator I'm attempting to create is similar to this one: http://www.stl.unitedway.org/give/impact-calculator/

I know html and css and but I'm a complete newbie when it comes to JQuery. I know sort of the logic I need.. First, use a selector to select the number inside the input text  box, and then check if it's a number. If it's a number, round that number and show the updated number within the text box. Then create an if else statement to evaluate the numbers that they put in, and output the results based on the dollar amount they put in inside a div below the input text.

I know that the form selector to use :text but then I'm not sure how to evaluate if the number they put in is a number, also not sure how round it off, how to write the if and else statement. I do know that I can use .text() or .html() to insert the results inside the div.

I would really appreciate any help..I've never done programming before but I volunteered because it's for a good cause... Thank you in advance, much appreciated..

Comment: Suggest you start by researching the javascript `Number` object and the `NAN` property (for validating a number) and the `Math` object `.round()` method (for rounding numbers). Attempt something and if you are still having problems, post a new question with the relevant code and errors

Comment: Hi Stephen, thank you for your response. You're right I think my question is too general. I'm going to attempt it tomorrow and write out my code here if I encounter any obstacle. Thank you.

Comment: To get you started, see [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sEY55/)

Comment: Thank you so much for giving me a good starting point, this helps a lot.

Comment: A few things to think about - perhaps radio buttons for the amounts ($5, $10, $20 etc); do you include hidden lists for all options initially and then just show one based on the selection or do you fetch the list from server using ajax

Comment: i think if i use hidden list, the code will be quite long as there are many dollar amounts breakpoints. i am not familiar with ajax. in your opinion, what would be the simplest and easiest approach? thanks again.

Comment: If you will have lots of lists with lots of items in each list, ajax is the way to go. There are plenty of resources/tutorials on the web. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think a simple approach would be to:

- Listen to the `keyup` event on the input element, then
- Determine if it is a number
- If it is, apply a function that rates it as "low", "medium", or "high" donation
- If it's not, display an error message accordingly

#### Markup

```
<input type="text" id="input" value="5" />
<div id="message"></div>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function () {

    var $input = $("#input");
    var $message = $("#message");
    var messages = {
        "low": "Some message about a low-tier donation",
        "medium": "Some message about a medium-tier donation",
        "high": "Some message about a high-tier donation",
        "error" : "Not a number value :("
    };

    function donationLevel(amt) {
        if (amt <= 25) {
            return "low";
        } else if (amt > 25 && amt <= 50) {
            return "medium";
        } else if (amt > 50) {
            return "high";
        }
    }

    $input.bind({
        'keyup': function () {
            var number = $(this).val();
            var isNumber = !isNaN(number);

            if (isNumber) {

                $message.text(messages[donationLevel(number)]);
            }
            else {
                $message.text(messages["error"]);
            }
        }
    });

    // Since we pre-filled our input with "5", 
    // trigger the keyup so we get our message

    $input.trigger('keyup');


});
```

#### [Example Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ETjTL/](http://jsfiddle.net/ETjTL/)